# Прав ли text.ru - одиночное деепричастие

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Проверяла орфографию с помощью этого сайта, и он мне вдруг выдает такое:

*"Он перевернулся на спину, сонно вздохнул, просыпаясь" - запятая не нужна, одиночное деепричастие в конце предложения выступает в роли наречия: "вздохнул просыпаясь.".* Правильно ли это? Почему-то до сих пор не могу поверить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Он перевернулся на спину, сонно вздохнул, просыпаясь.***

Постановка запятой — это **норма** для этого деепричастия, так как оно обозначает **дополнительное действие** даже в конце предложения, его сложно заменить наречием.

Отсутствие запятой в данном случае можно назвать чисто авторской пунктуацией, в большинстве тестов это деепричастие обособляется.

Примеры:

Э-эх! ― вздохнул Булыга, **закряхтел, просыпаясь.**  [Юрий Коваль. Лесник Булыга (1985)]

И тогда женщина **потянулась, просыпаясь.** ― Это ты, родной? ― спросила женщина. [Б. А. Пильняк. Простые рассказы (1923)]

Пример авторской пунктуации:

*Он перевернулся на спину, сонно вздохнул **не просыпаясь*** (во сне). Но и это авторский выбор, варианты с обособлением тоже часто встречаются.

Answer (score 1):

У них ведь там машинный алгоритм? В данном примере деепричастие "просыпаясь" не может выражать *образ действия* при вздохе (нельзя на вопрос "как он вздыхал?" ответить "просыпаясь"; здесь обозначено самостоятельное действие: что при этом он делал), поэтому запятая нужна.

> *Одиночное деепричастие не обособляется, если сохраняет значение*
>   *глагольности, указывая на **образ действия**.*
>   https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5/